# Route config on MVC 5

Tags: c#, controller, routes, asp.net-mvc-5

I newbie on MVC5 so I got many troubles which one is
Instead of typing **Home/Index/ID**, I type **/ID** it still understand. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your routes config file use the following route:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
        );
```

Now lets say your website name is `localhost:5050` when you will hit `localhost:5050/abc` it will open Index action of Home controller with `id = abc`

Comment: If id equal with name of controller? What do it do?

Comment: if you mean to say that localhost:5050/Home i.e here id = Home which is name of the controller it will still consider it as an id